# Changing pixel value in raster layer in QGIS using Python?

Tags: raster, gdal, pyqgis

I'd like to change the value of a pixel in a QGIS raster layer.  But the following Python code cannot do it.

```
r_layer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = r_layer.dataProvider()
from osgeo import gdal 
raster = gdal.Open(str(provider.dataSourceUri()))
np_array = raster.ReadAsArray()

np_array[1,2] = 5 

raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(np_array, 0, 0)
raster.GetRasterBand(1).FlushCache()
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not changed? I have code that does pretty much that using GDAL in C# and ArcObjects (lots more lines that you have) and have noted that the value doesn't *appear changed* until the pyramids are rebuilt and the layer removed and added again to refresh the cache. I open using OpenShared but I think that that would matter little.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the solution to my problem.  The array can be written after I added the option `gdal.GA_Update` to `Open(...)`

```
r_layer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = r_layer.dataProvider()
from osgeo import gdal 
raster = gdal.Open(str(provider.dataSourceUri()), gdal.GA_Update)
band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)

np_array = band.ReadAsArray()
np_array[0,0] =255
band.WriteArray(np_array)
```